# Boundedness of a given boundary value problem.

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, elliptic-pde

I've been given the following BVP:
\begin{align*}
-\Delta u = u- u^3,\: x\in \Omega 
\end{align*}\begin{align}
u = 0,\: x\in \partial \Omega
\end{align}
where $\Omega\subset \mathbb{R}^N$ is bounded.

I am supposed to show that $-1<  u(x)< 1$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}^N$.

I have experimented with sub/sup solutions, but this yields something different, and I suspect it is (very) wrong.

Any thoughts/hints?

Comment: Homework, voting to close.

Comment: You can just use plain vanilla maximum principles. Assume $u\geq1$ or $u\leq-1$ and see what happens. Also, are you sure you have to consider *all* $x\in\mathbb{R}^N$? In any case, I think your question is more suitable for MSE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiply your equation times the function $v(x) = \max(u-1,0)$. After you integrate by parts the Laplacian you will get an equality with opposite signs in each side that gives you a contradiction unless $v \equiv 0$.

Then do the same thing with $\min(u+1,0)$.

There are other ways to do it, including using sub/super-solutions.